# Mac Finder views in file manager on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, file-management

I have used Mac all my life. Now switched to Windows. I navigate in folders a lot. And I need to be fast at it. I'm very used to Finder (Mac file browser). I really like these two views on the Mac:

- [alpha](https://www.google.se/search?q=finder+mac&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=dcslVKO0LKSBywOB2oDoDw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1660&bih=926#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=7lOUQ4kLDDv-IM%253A%3BFw1zBGY4wLHDgM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fcdn.appstorm.net%252Fmac.appstorm.net%252Ffiles%252F2009%252F02%252Ffinder-integration.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmac.appstorm.net%252Freviews%252Fsyncplicity-innovative-backup-and-syncing%252F%3B606%3B433)
- [beta](http://www.google.se/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.osxdaily.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2010%2F02%2Fmac-os-x-finder-column-view.JPG&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fosxdaily.com%2F2010%2F03%2F25%2Fsetting-the-default-column-size-in-mac-os-x-finder-windows%2F&h=387&w=610&tbnid=y3HfB5VHqkcqdM%3A&zoom=1&docid=5wH43Bf4ZERtYM&ei=d8slVMvIOuS0ygO4_IGwCg&tbm=isch&ved=0CC4QMygOMA4&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=3097&page=1&start=0&ndsp=30)

**Can I get alpha and beta views on Windows?**

---

PS. What is "browse"?

Lets put three folders:

- folder 1

  - folder 1.1
  - folder 1.2

When I say *browse* I mean going from folder 1.1 to folder 1.2 quickly, without having to open two tabs.

PS 2. 
Another way of solving this problem would be to find an app that makes browsing files very fast.

Comment: what windows are you on?

Comment: I'm on windows 7.

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/408574/cant-find-a-windows-explorer-alternative-that-has-full-tree-view) looks like a similar question. Any of those answers help?